# $$ in KornShell

Tags: shell, ksh

What is the meaning of `$$` in KornShell? I guess it is associated with the process ID, but I want to know its exact meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$$` *is* the process id of the ksh process itself; `$PPID` is the process id of its parent.

Here's the [ksh (93) documentation for special parameters](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh-man.html#Parameter%20Expansion) (it's after the fold).  Same info [for ksh88](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh88-man.html#Parameter%20Substitution).

Comment: Thanks Martin, I got my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

It is used for making temporary names with the process id.  Say you need a file name but that name needs to be unique to the process you are in - so if more than one person runs the same ksh script they will not step on each other.

$$ is in bash, sh and other UN*X shells.

Comment: which process id, ksh itself, parent or child?

Comment: If you run a ksh script then ksh forks and the child runs as it's own process.  If you run something with "$ ./script" then it runs inline in the current process.

Comment: @Philip: huh?  surely you mean ". ./script" then it executes in the current shell

Comment: Yep - I ment $ . ./script - Can you edit and correct comments?